# Take tabulated data with start and end dates and transpose to a roadmap view, with items aligned to date columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table where each entry includes assignee, task name, start date, and due date.

Here is sample data:

| Owner | Task | Start Date | Due Date | Duration (days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jake | Task 1 | 2/21/2022 | 2/24/2022 | 4 |
| Jake | Task 2 | 2/28/2022 | 3/10/2022 | 9 |
| Jake | Task 3 | 3/14/2022 | 3/17/2022 | 4 |
| Fred | Task 4 | 3/21/2022 | 4/28/2022 | 29 |
| Fred | Task 5 | 5/2/2022 | 5/12/2022 | 9 |
| Jake | Task 6 | 5/16/2022 | 6/16/2022 | 24 |
| Jake | Task 7 | 6/20/2022 | 6/30/2022 | 9 |
| Jake | Task 8 | 7/4/2022 | 7/14/2022 | 9 |
| Jake | Task 9 | 7/18/2022 | 8/11/2022 | 19 |
| Jake | Task 10 | 8/15/2022 | 12/8/2022 | 84 |
| Jake | Task 11 | 12/12/2022 | 1/5/2023 | 19 |
| Erica | Task 1 | 1/9/2023 | 2/2/2023 | 19 |
| Erica | Task 2 | 2/6/2023 | 3/2/2023 | 19 |
| Erica | Task 3 | 3/6/2023 | 6/15/2023 | 74 |
| Erica | Task 4 | 2/21/2022 | 2/24/2022 | 4 |
| Erica | Task 5 | 2/28/2022 | 3/10/2022 | 9 |
| Erica | Task 6 | 3/14/2022 | 3/17/2022 | 4 |
| Erica | Task 7 | 3/21/2022 | 6/16/2022 | 64 |
| Erica | Task 8 | 6/20/2022 | 6/23/2022 | 4 |
| Erica | Task 9 | 6/27/2022 | 6/30/2022 | 4 |

I need to take that information, and display it on a roadmap, but with all tasks for one individual on a single row. Currently, I have tried the following:

`=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Sheet1!A1:E21, "Select B Where A='"&D5&"'", 1))`

I would like the task name to appear when the start date matches, and the ability to conditionally format all cells that are part of the duration. I have tried several approaches but don't seem to be making progress beyond my current point.

| Assignee | Num Tasks | Mar-7 | Mar-14 | Mar-21 | Mar-28 | Apr-4 | Apr-11 | Apr-18 | Apr-25 | May-2 | May-9 | May-16 | May-23 | May-30 | Jun-6 | Jun-13 | Jun-20 | Jun-27 | Jul-4 | Jul-11 | Jul-18 | Jul-25 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jake | 14 | Task1 | Task2 | Task3, | Task4 | Task5, | Task6 | Task7, | Task8 | Task9, | Task10 | Task11 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Erica | 6 | Task1 | Task2 | Task3 | Task4 | Task5 | Task6 | Task7 | Task8 | Task9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Here is an image of the desired output as well.

[image]

Comment: Here is a spreadsheet created specifically to answer this question.  It will remain editable for 30 days from now and stay view only in perpetuity so that others can benefit from the sample sheet.  And so that other volunteers can help in a shared space.  I will post an answer shortly that includes some demonstration there.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xEAkzaonimHY0c8959EoXcT2NKU_6a3G7IwFOv2KQA/edit

Comment: what is the date range you would like to see?  ALL DATES? or only dates that are in the future?

Comment: Good question, outside of that image, there is a cell that drives the start date in the roadmap, so it can all be dynamically driven as time goes on. 

For example, if that start date is APR1, then it will begin the roadmap with the month prior, and continue into the future. Does this help?

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: thankfully, there is a sheet associated with this question that will not allow anyone to access the OPs email address and the sheet associated with this question is in no danger of disappearing.  It will remain associated with this question in perpetuity. @TheMaster

Comment: @MattKing It still is a external link. And most importantly, it reduces the quality of the question.Askers can basically ask their project goals and get readymade solutions. SO is not a support forum. We need questions that help future viewers and that can only happen, if askers ask programming questions and not "how to achieve their company's goal". To ask such questions, they need to cut their goal down to a [mre] and that includes spending time to create such a example.Kindly read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/)(and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/)).

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for the direction. When I am out of meetings I will circle back and update the question, and test the answers that have been provided. Apologies for the noob formatting of the question.

Comment: `Mar-7` doesn't match `Jake`'s ``Startdate``. So, why `Task1`?

Comment: @TheMaster yeah that's a copy pasta error on my part. Apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this question type's popularity that Matt refers to in his answer, perhaps it is worthwhile to mention the "conventional" `filter()` pattern often used to create these sorts of timelines.

With task owner name, task name, start date and due date in columns `A2:D`, you can list task owners in cell `G2` with `=unique(A2:A)` and the number of tasks in cell `H2` with `=counta( iferror( filter( B$2:B, A$2:A = G2 ) ) )`.

To list all the weeks from the first start date to the last due date, put this in cell `I1`:

`=sequence(1, (max(C2:D) - min(C2:D)) / 7, min(C2:D), 7)`

Format the `sequence()` results as **Format > Number > Date**.

Finally, to list task names by owner name and week, put this in cell `I2`:

`iferror( textjoin( ", ", true, filter( $B$2:$B, $A$2:$A = $G2, $C$2:$C <= I$1, I$1 <= $D$2:$D) ) )`

See the '[Conventional solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xEAkzaonimHY0c8959EoXcT2NKU_6a3G7IwFOv2KQA/edit#gid=601605477)' tab in the sample spreadsheet Matt kindly created.

Further, the recently introduced lambda functions let you create the whole result table with one formula, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  uniqueNames, names, tasks, startDates, dueDates, 
  lambda( 
    weeks, 
    makearray( 
      rows(uniqueNames), columns(weeks) + 2, 
      lambda( 
        row, column, 
        lambda( 
          name, week, 
          lambda( 
            numTasksByName, filterTasksByWeek, 
            ifs( 
              (row = 1) * (column = 1), "Assignee", 
              (row = 1) * (column = 2), "Num tasks", 
              row = 1, week, 
              column = 1, name, 
              column = 2, numTasksByName, 
              true, iferror( textjoin( ", ", true, filterTasksByWeek) ) 
            ) 
          )(
             counta(iferror(filter(tasks, names = name))), 
             filter(tasks, names = name, startDates <= week, week <= dueDates) 
           ) 
        )( 
           index(uniqueNames, row - 1, 1), 
           index(weeks, 1, column - 2) 
         ) 
      ) 
    )
  )(sequence(1, (max(dueDates) - min(startDates)) / 7, min(startDates), 7))
)(unique(A2:A), A2:A, B2:B, C2:C, D2:D)
```

The benefit of this pattern is that it is fairly easy to adjust the contents of the table, and there is no need to copy formulas down when more data becomes available. The use of nested lambdas lets us use readable names instead of range references within the various functions.

See the '[Lambda solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10xEAkzaonimHY0c8959EoXcT2NKU_6a3G7IwFOv2KQA/edit#gid=1452819312)' tab in Matt's spreadsheet. The formula in cell `G1` creates the whole result table automatically.

Comment: Thank you for this! When I get out of my next set of meetings, I will also give this a shot.

Comment: With 5 nested lambdas, I'm sure this can't be used  if there are any significant number of rows to processed.

Comment: Yeah... the formula seems to handle 1000 rows fine, but chokes at some point before 2000 rows. That limitation seems acceptable for the use case presented in the question.

Comment: While two of the answers did what I needed, it was the textjoin + filter that ended up being more performant. Appreciate the lengths you went to teach me something new.

Answer (score 1):

this is an extremely common question, and there are many answers out there on the internet, but there is not a common enough syntax in describing what you want to make it easy to google.

I built something in two steps rather than one, because I've found that with this solution, people often hadn't thought of having their task data "flattened" the way I've done on the helper tab.  The database structure of the task dates for the gantt chart will likely be useful for you for lots of other things.  I'd recommend that you leave it in place, (but possibly hidden) on your real sheet so that you can reference it for other dashboard-ey purposes.

I made a new tab on this sheet and put this formula in cell D3.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3:B5&D2:2,{MK_Help_Back_End!A:A&MK_Help_Back_End!C:C,MK_Help_Back_End!B:B},2,0)))
```

It relies on a "back end" helper tab with this formula in cell A1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN('Data from OP'!A2:A&"|"&'Data from OP'!B2:B&"|"&'Data from OP'!C2:C+SEQUENCE(1,MAX('Data from OP'!E2:E),0)&"|"&'Data from OP'!D2:D),"|",0,0),"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col3<=Col4 label Col1'Name',Col2'Task',Col3'Date'"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I hadn't previously used FLATTEN. Wasn't aware of the benefits here. I learned something new. Really appreciate the time you took, and I hope you have an excellent day.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, IF(x<>"", IFERROR(TEXT(x*1, "m/d/e"), x), ))
 (QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet1!A2:A&"|"&Sheet1!B2:B&"|"&Sheet1!C2:C+
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(Sheet1!E2:E),0)&"|"&Sheet1!D2:D), "|",,), 
 "where Col3<=Col4 and Col4 is not null", ), 
 "select Col1,max(Col2) 
  where Col3*1>="&DATEVALUE("4/1/2022")&" 
  group by Col1 pivot Col3 label Col1'​'" )))
```

[image]

Comment: he wants to use all his own formulas for dates and names etc.  we're supposed to just help with the task population